# Is there any volume change event on AudioContext (HTML5)?

Tags: html, audiocontext

I am developing an app using audio nodes and I need to know if the volume is changed, for example if the device volume is modified using the physical buttons. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use  `volumeChange`  sent when the audio volume changes (both when the volume is set and when the muted attribute is changed).

see [Media Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) for info